# Replacing all matched strings in a file with matcher.replaceall in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to replace **only matched strings** in a file by using `matcher.replaceAll()`.Like below

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, BadLocationException {

      FileInputStream fis = null;
      String output = new Scanner(new File("C:/file.in")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();//file.in contains HTML text
      String s2 = null;
      StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
      for (int i=0; i<patternList.size(); i++)//PatternList contains names to be extracted from file
      {
          Matcher matcher = patternList.get(i).matcher(output);
          while (matcher.find()) 
          {
                String matched = matcher.group();//I need to replace only matched strings returned by matcher
                s2=matcher.replaceAll("<span style='background-color:red;'>"+matched+"</span>");
      File file = new File("C:/data/filename.in");
      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(s2);
        bw.close();
          }   
      }
```

The resulting string `s2` updated with only last string in PatternList.Each time i am overwriting the string with newly matched string. How can i get the final big string which is updated with all matched strings(names in patternlist).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have lot of redundant code. You definitely don't need a list of `Pattern` objects.

Consider this code:

```
String output = new Scanner(new File("C:/file.in")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
String repl = output.replaceAll("\b(Shannon|Sperling|Kim|Tammy|Nancy|Lana)\b", 
              <span style='background-color:red;'>$1</span>"); 

File file = new File("C:/data/filename.in");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write( repl );
bw.close();
```

Comment: I have just showed 6 strings in the example for simplicity, In reality i have thousands of strings to be updated.That can be achieved only through "matcher". Whenever the match occurs, i need to update it.

Comment: If you have thousands of keywords even then building a fewer Pattern objects is possible by putting an `|` between them (as shown above) rather than creating one Pattern/Matcher for each keyword.

Comment: Those strings are stored in dictionary, some times they may be multiples of 1000's.I am reading the entry in a dictionary, building a pattern then checking for existance in a file.The way you said does not look like good way.Infact it is not at all possible to get all strings and put it there with "|" as seperator.

Comment: Every dictionary of words can return your String words so not sure what you're talking about. In your question you have `String[] names`. Think of reasons why your question is NOT getting any answers.

Comment: Your code works fine for replacing strings in a specified file.Because you are replacing all strings in one line and assigning to the result string.But my requirement is different.First i have to get the dictionary entry, build a pattern and use for matcher to get the matched string with START and END index(Which are very important for my project), then just highlight the matched strings in a file.The reason why i should i use Dictionary is they will change constantly.Suppose if i have 3000 names in a dictionary, how it works with your code.

Comment: :anubhava:am i still unclear?I am strugling with this problem.

Comment: Yes still unclear. I am not convinced about use of list of Pattern. Why can't you just run a loop with the words from dictionary and do all `String#replace`

Comment: I am using the pattern for some other purpose of my project.I must do it in that way for getting start and end index.So i only has to highlight the background of matched strings,not `all entries of dictionary`.It is normal that some of entries will not be matched.

Comment: @user3004131: It will be helpful if you can show the actual code that you're trying to do rather than that sample in your question. Your question is doing something else and your comments are saying different things.

Comment: anubhava:Edited the question now.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve the problem after changing `s2` to `output`.Assign the result(`matcher.replaceAll`) to `output` instead of `s2`. Now all the matched strings replaced with color tag.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, BadLocationException {
FileInputStream fis = null;
  String output = new Scanner(new File("C:/file.in")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();//file.in contains HTML text
  String s2 = null;
  StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
  for (int i=0; i<patternList.size(); i++)//PatternList contains names to be extracted from file
  {
      Matcher matcher = patternList.get(i).matcher(output);
      while (matcher.find()) 
      {
            String matched = matcher.group();//I need to replace only matched strings returned by matcher
            output=matcher.replaceAll("<span style='background-color:red;'>"+matched+"</span>");
  File file = new File("C:/data/filename.in");
  FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write(output);
    bw.close();
      }   
  }
```